# Find rows with same values in Column A and exclude them from result if value in Column B differs

Tags: sql

I have a column A with service name, and a column B with the state of these services.
I have the same services deployed on multiple hosts but with different states.

| Service | state |
| --- | --- |
| ServiceA | OK |
| ServiceB | NOK |
| ServiceA | NOK |
| ServiceB | NOK |

I want to display only services where all rows related to this service are NOK--if a serviceX is in the OK state I want to exclude it.

In my example I would like to retrieve only ServiceB, because there is no row where ServiceB is in a different state than NOK in the whole table.

```
With a :
SELECT service,state,count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY service,state
```

I'm able to retrieve a counter for each different value:

| Service | state | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ServiceA | OK | 1 |
| ServiceB | NOK | 2 |
| ServiceA | NOK | 1 |

`WHERE state != 'NOK'` discards services in the OK state, but it gives a wrong result as serviceA will appear whereas one row is not 'NOK'.

Comment: please remember to add formatting to the sql snippet and the tables on your question

Comment: Hi, this is a mariaDB. Sorry re_arg I'm really not expert in DB and I don't really know what a snippet is 

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @re_arg "code snippet" is a special term on this site for certain formatting for presenting & executing html/css/javascript code. So please talk about code formatted in a "code block" for other languages. Debug questions require code & prose constituting a [mre] & other code questions are best with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in-subquery for that:

"Select all distinct services which do not belong to a set where a service has OK state"

```
select distinct Service
from t
where Service not in (
  select Service
  from t
  where state='OK'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT service, state, count(*) FROM table WHERE state = 'NOK' GROUP BY service, state;
```

Comment: Hi Cameron,
Thx for your help, unfortunately your query provide same output of mine, just masking the OK state, I was looking for a way to discard all services if at least one entry was not 'NOK' ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways that you can do this, in my opinion one of the easiest is with a subquery. You want services where **all** hosts are `NOK` that is the same to say that you want services where **none** of the hosts are `OK`, right? That is easier to find: all services where **at least** one service is `OK`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT service
FROM services
WHERE state = 'OK'
```

Those are the services you **don't** want, so to get the ones you do want (the rest), you can just select all services not returned by that query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT service from services where service not in (
  SELECT DISTINCT service
  FROM services
  WHERE state = 'OK' )
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c452a/9/0

Hope that helps